# Single quote argument is converted to double quoted argument when passed to oracle function and called from shell script

Tags: oracle, shell

I am trying to execute one oracle function from shell script.
This function just takes two string arguments and returns full their concatenated string.
Here is the oracle function

```
create or replace package temp as
    function getName(v_fname in varchar2, v_lname varchar2) return varchar2;
end temp;

create or replace package body temp as
    function getName(v_fname in varchar2, v_lname in varchar2) return varchar2 is
    v_fullname varchar2(17);
    begin
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name);
        v_fullname := concat(v_fname,v_lname);
        return v_fullname;
    end getName;
end temp;
/
```

Here is snippet of shell script

```
fullname=$(sqlplus -s myuser/password@DBinstance << !
set heading off
set feedback off
SELECT TEMP.GETNAME('Vishal','Tavande') FROM DUAL;
!)
echo $fullname
```

When I execute `SELECT TEMP.GETNAME('Vishal','Tavande') FROM DUAL` in Oracle, I can get the result as 'VishalTavande'; but when I execute this in Shell, what I get is

> fullname=SELECT TEMP.GETNAME("Vishal","Tavande") FROM DUAL ERROR at
>   line 1: ORA-00904: "Vishal": invalid identifier

Any help is really appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: Which shell? Works as expected for me in bash/ksh under Linux...

Comment: I think I got the answer... I'll have to store the values of strings in variables with "'"' format and use those variables in function. 
e.g. var1="'Vishal"'
var2="'Tavande"'
and call method as SELECT TEMP.GETNAME($var1,$var2) FROM DUAL

Comment: I'm not sure you've shown your actual shell script then; were you really already using variables in the call, not the hard-coded values you showed?